# How to list class methods in gdb?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I've been googling for this and checking through the gdb manual but can't seem to find an answer to what I'm trying to do.

Is there a way to get gdb to print out a listing of all the methods for a given class type? The print command only seems to show the data members and fields, none of the methods are displayed for it.

Additionally, to take it a step further, is there a way to print all the correct virtual methods given a base *pointer? Say like for example:

```
struct A
{
  virtual void foo() {}
};

struct B : public A
{
  void foo() {}
};

int main()
{
  A *b = new B;
}
```

How can I get gdb to print variable *b and have it show the correct virtual method(s)?

Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `ptype`.

Suppose I add these lines to your example:

```
A alpha;
B beta;
```

Now in gdb I can ask for a description of a class type (or an instance of one):

```
(gdb) ptype alpha
type = class A {
  public:
    virtual void foo();
}

(gdb) ptype A
type = class A {
  public:
    virtual void foo();
}

(gdb) ptype beta
type = class B : public A {
  public:
    virtual void foo();
}

(gdb) ptype B
type = class B : public A {
  public:
    virtual void foo();
}
```

If I try that with a pointer, I get the declared type:

```
(gdb) ptype b
type = class A {
  public:
    virtual void foo();
} *
```

**If I want the real type, I must set the `print object' variable:**

```
(gdb) set print object on
(gdb) ptype b
type = /* real type = B * */
class A {
  public:
    virtual void foo();
} *
```

and then call `ptype` again to see what `B` has (I don't know how to do it in one step).

Comment: Thank you, that will do nicely

Comment: Can I also see the members of standard library types? If I add `std::vector<int> v` and then enter `ptype v`, I just get: `type = std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @user2023370: What do you want to get? The type of `v[0]` (i.e. `int`)? I can't test it right now, but I would expect `ptype v[0]` to work.

Comment: In your answer when you enter `ptype alpha` you get more than `type = class A`.