# Why does "gdb" print the class methods of specific classes?

Tags: c++, stl, gdb

## The context

I recently found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956024/how-to-list-class-methods-in-gdb) since I was searching a way to list all the available methods present in a class, so I started experimenting with the `ptype` command which made me post this question

Consider the following file

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

int main() {
  std::array <int, 1> a;
  std::vector <int> v;
  std::list <int> l;

  return 0;
}
```

I can list all methods present in the `array` class by doing the following

```
g++ -g main.cpp && \
  gdb -q -batch -ex 'break 10' -ex 'run' -ex 'ptype a' ./a.out
```

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1179: file main.cpp, line 10.

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:10
10    return 0;
type = struct std::array<int, 1> [with _Tp = int] {
    std::__array_traits<_Tp, 1>::_Type _M_elems;
  public:
    void fill(reference);
    void swap(std::array<_Tp, 1> &);
    iterator begin(void);
    iterator begin(void) const;
    iterator end(void);
(... more methods ...)
```

However, this doesn't happen with the `vector` and `list` classes (see below).

Executing `ptype` on an instance of the `vector` class

```
g++ -g main.cpp && \
  gdb -q -batch -ex 'break 10' -ex 'run' -ex 'ptype v' ./a.out
```

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1179: file main.cpp, line 10.

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:10
10    return 0;
type = std::vector<int>
```

Executing `ptype` on an instance of the `list` class

```
g++ -g main.cpp && \
  gdb -q -batch -ex 'break 10' -ex 'run' -ex 'ptype l' ./a.out
```

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1179: file main.cpp, line 10.

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:10
10    return 0;
type = std::list<int>
```

## The question

Why does `ptype` prints all the methods present in the `array` class but doesn't do the same with the `vector` and `list` classes?

Comment: As templates only instantiate methods if needed, it may be that you simply have non because you don't use your vector or list. You may try to do some useful things and take a look that the templated code is not fully inlined. O0 is a chance but never a guarantee for todays compilers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's gdb bug. I have reproduced this behavior for `std::vector` on my box, `ptype v` does not output `std::vector` members:

```
(gdb) ptype v
type = std::vector<int>
```

On the other hand `ptype/r v` does output members:

```
(gdb) ptype/r v
type = class std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > : protected std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> > {
  private:
    static bool _S_nothrow_relocate(std::true_type);
    static bool _S_nothrow_relocate(std::false_type);
    static bool _S_use_relocate(void);
    ...
```

`ptype/r` should only display members in more verbose raw form compared to ordinary `ptype`, see in [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols.html):

> Display in “raw” form. Normally, GDB substitutes template parameters and typedefs defined in a class when printing the class’
> members. The /r flag disables this.

But ordinary `ptype` does not display anything. As a workaround you can try to use `ptype/r`.

Comment: Weird, it's working for me for all 3 variables. Tested with gcc-10.2 and gdb-8.3.

Comment: Not sure this is a bug, seems like its related to `gdb` either calling or not calling the appropriate pretty-printers